# Energy in harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, virial-theorem

The expectation value of the potential energy is exactly half the total according to Griffiths. Is that case always true for quantum harmonic oscillator? Is that the case also for classical harmonic oscillator?

Comment: @Qmechanic I really did not understand the virial thoerem. I learned 2<T>=n<V>. I could not use the case in classical harmonic oscillator since I did not understand meaning of n.

Comment: $n$ is the power of the potential. For the harmonic oscillator $n=2$. Next use that $E= \langle T \rangle + \langle V \rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true in both cases and an even more general statement can be made. For a potential of the form $V(r)=\alpha r^n$, the expectation value of the kinetic an potential energy is related by
$$
2 \langle T \rangle = n \langle V \rangle.
$$
For the case of the harmonic oscillator, $n=2$.

See [virial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem) for details.